# gnuplot: make autotitle ignore header lines

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I want to use gnuplot to plot several lines from a csv file which has a not fixed number of header lines and columns. The file might look like this:

```
HEADERLINE1           = TEXTTEXTTEXT 
HEADERLINE2           = TEXTTEXTTEXT
HEADERLINE3           = 1248243 
HEADERLINE4           = 329340


COLUMN_X      COLUMN_1       COLUMN_2
       1       36.9194        30.0000
       2       19.0977        20.0000
       3       12.9250        10.0000
       4       10.7134         0.0000
```

Normally without the header lines I would use something like this:

```
stats 'datafile.csv' nooutput
set key autotitle columnheader
plot for [t=2:STATS_columns] \
  datafile \
  using 1:t \
  with linespoints
```

However with the header lines those are used by the autotitle command. Is there a way to tell autotitle to pick the columnheads from the actual columns / second block / ignore the header?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that there are always at least two blank lines between the header lines and the data, you can use `index`. `stats` gives you some warnings but the result is as desired:

```
stats "so.dat" nooutput
set key autotitle columnheader
plot for [t=2:STATS_columns] \
  "so.dat" \
  index 1\
  using 1:t \
  with linespoints
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Yes skipping is an option but as I said the number of header lines is not fixed. So I would need to find out the number of header lines before and I don't know how to do that in gnuplot :)

Comment: Oops sorry minor detail ;-) that escaped me. Have edited with a different solution

Comment: Awesome thanks, I didn't know about `index`. Any magic to suppress the warnings? ;)

Comment: `stats "so.dat" index 1 every ::1 nooutput` seems to do the trick of skipping the header lines and columnheaders.